# How cancel SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, savechanges

I make first SaveChanges and flies exception (UpdateException).
And I make second SaveChanges and againe fliyng first erorr.
What to do about it

```
bool isUpdate = false;
var resource = new Resource() { url = tbUrl.Text };
//block1
try
{
    context.Resource.AddObject(resource);
    context.SaveChanges();
    isUpdate = true;
}
catch (UpdateException ex)
{

}

//block2
if (!isUpdate)
{
    resource = (from res in context.Resource where res.url == tbUrl.Text select res).First();
    context.NameToResourcer.AddObject(new NameToResourcer()
                    {
                        id_resource = resource.id,
                        name = tag
                    });
    context.SaveChanges();//error!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calls to `SaveChanges` should be wrapped in a transaction. Typically using a `TransactionScope`.  Then you can roll-back the transaction if one of the calls to SaveChanges fails.

---

*Edit:*

For some examples, see these 2 MSDN pages:

[System.Transactions.TransactionScope Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

[How to: Manage Transactions in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx)

Comment: I'm where you heard about this, you can sample?

Comment: See the Edit in my answer above. I added some helpful links that have examples in them.